# SQLite Select from where column contains string?

Tags: sqlite

What I currently have selects based on a column having the same value..

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE uuid = ?"
```

But what if I want to return a row based on one of the columns "containing" a string value? Some pseudo code would be:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE column CONTAINS mystring
```

Any help is appreciated, I have been searching for other answers but to no avail.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE column LIKE '%mystring%'` will do it.

`LIKE` means we're not doing an exact match (`column = value`), but doing some more fuzzy matching. "%" is a wildcard character - it matches 0 or more characters, so this is saying "all rows where the column has 0 or more chars followed by "mystring" followed by 0 or more chars".

Comment: what if the "mystring" is a parameter? i.e. the function is `findAll( mystring: String)` and the query contains "%:mystring%" , but it gives the error "mystring is a parameter not used"

Comment: Edit: the error is "error: Unused parameter: mystring"

Comment: @MarcoOttina Suggest you ask a new question with all details included - i.e. What do you mean by "the query contains "%mystring%" ? - the results of the query contains the literal string "%mystring%" or you expect the results of the query to match "%mystring%".

Comment: You didn't saw the ":", meaning that this shall be considered as a value picked from function parameters but it's parsed as a simple string.
I've solved using someone else's solution: `instr( theColumn, :theParameter ) > 0`

Answer (score 12):

Use `LIKE` clause. 
E.g. if your string contains `"pineapple123"`, your query would be:

```
SELECT * from users WHERE column LIKE 'pineapple%';
```

And if your string always starts with any number and ends with any number like `"345pineapple4565"`, you can use:

```
SELECT * from users WHERE column LIKE "%pineapple%";
```

Answer (score 6):

Checking variable substring ( a more generic answer )

you should use `'%'||?||'%'` instead

for example in python we'll have something like this:

`curser.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE column LIKE '%'||?||'%'", (variable,) )`

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Just another way using [instr](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr), do not need to supply additional character.

```
Select * from repos where instr("column_name", "Search_string") > 1
```

Comment: realize this is old ?, but if the column name begins with 'search string', you change it to > 0:  `select * from repos where instr(column_name,'search_string') > 0`

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this problem and solved it such you can find the string 'time'

```
text = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE column=" + "'" + str(time) + "'"

cursor.execute(text)
```

The issue I found was that when you pass in the string time directly as:
`..WHERE column=" + time)` 
it formats `'time'` as `"time"` when you want it to format as `'time'` which must be to do with the way SQLite is wrote to handle the arguments its passed.

I have time stamped all entries into a database and now I can recall any data from a specific time.